# PointCloud visualization & VTK window rendering on Mojave

Tags: c, vtk, nswindow, point-cloud-library, macos-mojave

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread

```
[General] NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff33c942fd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5e369a17 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff33cade59 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff312545ca -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 317
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff312519f7 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1479
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff3125142a -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 45
    6   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.1.dylib  0x0000000108c9f11a _ZN20vtkCocoaRenderWindow13CreateAWindowEv + 1936
    7   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.1.dylib  0x0000000108c9f7e9 _ZN20vtkCocoaRenderWindow10InitializeEv + 205
    8   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.1.dylib  0x0000000108c9d584 _ZN20vtkCocoaRenderWindow5StartEv + 18
    9   libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.1.dylib  0x0000000108c9bc7c _ZN30vtkCocoaRenderWindowInteractor10InitializeEv + 56
    10  libpcl_visualization.1.9.dylib      0x000000010ce53dcf _ZN3pcl13visualization13PCLVisualizer16createInteractorEv + 207
    11  libpcl_visualization.1.9.dylib      0x000000010ce53818 _ZN3pcl13visualization13PCLVisualizerC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEb + 904
    12  libpcl_visualization.1.9.dylib      0x000000010ce7c791 _ZN3pcl13visualization11CloudViewer16CloudViewer_implclEv + 49
    13  libpcl_visualization.1.9.dylib      0x000000010ce7ccfe 
_ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEMN3pcl13visualization11CloudViewer16CloudViewer_implEFvvEPSA_EEEEEPvSF_ + 62
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5fd2b2eb _pthread_body + 126
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5fd2e249 _pthread_start + 66
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5fd2a40d thread_start + 13

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!
```